# Referring a member variable from self invoking nested function

Tags: javascript, nested-function

I have this piece of code

```
var f = function() {
    this.x = 100;
    (
        function() {
            x = 20;
        }
    )();
};

var a = new f;
console.log(a.x);
```

I am wondering why a new variable x is created at global scope, and the output is 100, not 20.
If I write instead

> var x = 100;

the nested function changes the same x's value.
It seems that creating x via

> this.x = 100

places x outside the scope of function f. If that is the case, where is it defined? And how can it be accessed?

EDIT : Fixed a typo : console.log(a.x) instead of console.log(x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement:

```
this.x = 100;
```

Does not create a variable in the current scope, it sets a property `x` on whatever object `this`refers to. In your case `this` will be the object just instantiated via `new f`, the same object that will be returned by `f` and assigned to `a`.

When you say:

```
x = 20;
```

JavaScript looks for an `x` in the current scope and doesn't find it, so it looks in the next scope up, etc., until it gets to the global scope. If it doesn't find `x` in any accessible scope it creates a new global variable as you have seen.

To access the property `x` from within a nested function the usual practice is to store a reference to `this` in a local variable and then the nested function can reference that variable:

```
var f = function() {
    var self = this;       // keep a reference to this

    this.x = 100;
    (
        function() {
            self.x = 20;   // use the self reference from the containing scope
        }
    )();
};

var a = new f;
console.log(a.x);          // will now be 20
```

The other way to do it is to reference `this.x` in the inner function, provided you call the inner function via the [`.call()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) so that you can explictly set `this` to be the same as in the (outer) `f` function:

```
var f = function() {
    this.x = 100;
    (
        function() {
            this.x = 20;
        }
    ).call(this);
};

var a = new f;
console.log(a.x);
```

Further reading:

- [Working With Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_this_for_object_references)
- [`this` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Very well explained, and also taught me call() method!

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, variables have function-level scope. Also, this:

```
this.x = 100;
```

is differnt from:

```
x = 20;
```

because in later case, `x` has global (you have not used `var` before it) scope eg it becomes part of `window` object.

---

Also when you are doing:

```
var a = new f;
console.log(x);
```

You are accessing global variable `x` set via `x = 20;` whereas you are suppossed to do:

```
var a = new f;
console.log(a.x);
```

Comment: It was a typo, I meant console.log(a.x), sorry.

Comment: Any way to make 'x=20' refer to 'this.x' instead of creating a new 'x' in global scope?

Answer (score 1):

```
var f = function() {

    this.x = 100;
    console.log(this);
    // f

    (function() {
      console.log(this);
      // DOMWindow. So x is a property of window because you're not declaring it with var
      x = 20;
    })();
};
```

if you want to assign the product of the anonymous function to the scope of `f` then the following will work:

```
var f = function() {
    this.x = (function() {
      var x = 20; // Local scope
      return x;
    })();
};

console.log( (new f().x) );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change a member function in a nested, anonymous subfunction, you might want to create a pointer to 'this' within scope, as follows:

```
var f = function() {
    this.x = 100; // set the member value
    var self = this; // pointer to the current object within this function scope
    (
        function(){
            self.x = 20; // 'self' is in scope
        }();
    )();
};

var a = new f;

console.log(a.x); // Output: 20
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable without `var`, the variable is in global scope.

Comment: Yeah, but it's parent scope does have a variable named x (declared and defined via this.x). Should it not refer to that? Or does this.x effectively declares it elsewhere?

Comment: @kaustubh No, it's not refer to that.